# Select id from last inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I have table named faculty and its attribute are `id`, `Name` and `dean`. I want to get last inserted record id in this table.

eg:

```
id  Name  dean
1   abc   xyz
2   efg   sss
3   ert   yui
```

I just want to get 3rd id only, not 3rd row.
Just last inserted id that is 3 in this case.

Comment: `select max(id) as last_id from faculty`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in your stored procedure to get last inserted record id.

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() :- It will returns the last identity value inserted into an 
identity column in the same scope.

SELECT @@IDENTITY :- @@IDENTITY will return the last identity value entered 
into a table in your current session. 

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’) :- IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and
session; it is limited to a specified table.
```

There are other options also such as

```
1. Select Top 1 id From Table Order by id desc

2. SELECT max(id) FROM table
```

Refer msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx 
and 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` will return the last generated Identity value in any session in any table, `IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')` will return the last generated Identity value for TableName in any session and finally `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will return the last generated Identity value in this current session. The safest option is `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but if your are dealing with multiple inserts then `OUTPUT` clause is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use 
@@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT

see this Link [@@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE-IDENTITY-IDENT-C)